# Wicket infinite reloading page while using Lazy Loading panels

Tags: java, exception, lazy-loading, wicket, infinite-loop

I have the Wicket Page, which only creates in constructor the ListView. These list view items are only components present on the page.

For loading these components I am using AsynchronousUpdatePanel from third side library:
https://gist.github.com/jonnywray/594468

I want to use asynchronous panel, because some components are loading 300 ms, but some 10 seconds.

Problem is, that **sometimes when I want to refresh the page some infinite cycle begins and the page reloads over and over again**. The lazy indicators are shown and after few ms page refresh them again. User must close this browser tab and start again.

When infinite cycle starts, the **StalePageException** is thrown again and again, which starting the page reload. Then, the app console is full of these:

```
WARN RequestCycleExtra - ********************************
WARN RequestCycleExtra - Handling the following exception
org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.StalePageException: A request to page '[Page class = *.*Page, id = 1, render count = 2]' has been made with stale 'renderCount'. The page will be re-rendered.
WARN RequestCycleExtra - ********************************
```

I Cant find, what I am doing wrong. Components, which are loading have models, which loads in Callable thread on background through AsynchronousUpdatePanel and after that, the onPostSuccess method is called and in this method I am replacing the lazy indicator with my panel (component), which has the loaded model now.

Thank you for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a quickstart and ask for help on the Wicket mailing list. Without debugging it's hard to find the cause of the problem.

Note that AsynchronousUpdatePanel/FutureUpdateBehavior seem to violate some Wicket principles (e.g. transient non-serializable "future" fields).

Furthermore since Wicket 8 AjaxLazyLoadPanel has support for parallel asynchronous lazy-loading, maybe you want to try that instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will see the Wicket 8 LazyLoad and if it wont fix the issue, I will provide some quickstart project. :)

Comment: I have changed my lazy load panel for standard wicket 8 lazy load panels. It wont fix. I have found out, that when I remove this from constructor of the page, the problem disappears, so I think, that the problem is something with wicket behaviors.
add(new AjaxEventBehavior("DOMContentLoaded") {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Override
   protected void onEvent(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    target.appendJavaScript("someJavascript");
   }
  });

Comment: When some behaviors (timer, event, or simply AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior) exists on the page, the problem is here. Infinite reloading and StalePageException starts.